# create shared code for Outlook 2007 and 2010 VSTO 4.0 add-in with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm creating an Outlook add-in that uses .NET 4.0 VSTO, Visual Studio 2010 that targets Outlook 2010/2007.

I will be creating a different Ribbon so will need to create 3 projects:
- 2010 ribbon
- 2007 ribbon
- shared code

My question is, how do I get the delegates in shared code (ie when a user clicks on a Ribbon/Command  bar button, I'd like to have it share the same code if possible).

```
private void btnRibbon_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
       //Event triggered by user clicking ribbon button
}
```

Or am I going to have to duplicate my code base for 2007/2010 for this??

Thanks!!
m

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What you are trying to do is a bad idea anyways.  You should just have two different versions of the code.  You can share code by importing a single library.

Comment: DUH -- nevermind....basically I'm just going to create functions for all the user interactions in the class library.